# matrix of mean 0 and standard deviation 0.1 with python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

How do I initialize a matrix with random values so that the mean should be 0 and standard deviation  should be 0.1? Is there a easy way to do this with python??

Some one please tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 6):

I am assuming that you mean that each entry of the matrix should be drawn from a normal distribution with mean 0 and standard deviation 0.1. This can be achieved using numpy with:

```
from numpy import random

a = random.normal(0, 0.1, (10, 10))
```

This will create a 10x10 random matrix.